# LEFT JOIN expression not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to do a query with a left outer join just like below, however Access is showing a warning dialog "JOIN expression not supported".I understand that Access doesn't support INNER JOIN nested inside a LEFT JOIN but as I am a beginner in SQL I don't see any other way to get the same result.

The goal of the query is to get everything that is in the select even when InvoiceItems.Amount is null.

```
SELECT MainOrder.OrderNumber, OrderComponent.ArticleNumber, SupplierOrderMain.*, InvoiceItems.Amount
FROM InvoiceItems LEFT JOIN
     ((MainOrder INNER JOIN
       OrderComponent 
       ON MainOrder.OrderNumber = OrderComponent.OrderNumber
      ) INNER JOIN
      SupplierOrderMain
      ON OrderComponent.ID = SupplierOrderMain.OrderComponentID
     )
     ON InvoiceItems.OrderComponent = OrderComponent.ID;
```

Comment: If you want help formulating a solution, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want outer joins in this situation at all (you don't explain why).  But just start with the table where you want to keep everything and work from there:

```
SELECT MainOrder.OrderNumber, OrderComponent.ArticleNumber, SupplierOrderMain.*, InvoiceItems.Amount
FROM ((InvoiceItems LEFT JOIN
       OrderComponent
       ON InvoiceItems.OrderComponent = OrderComponent.ID
      ) LEFT JOIN
      MainOrder      
      ON MainOrder.OrderNumber = OrderComponent.OrderNumber
     ) LEFT JOIN
     SupplierOrderMain
     ON OrderComponent.ID = SupplierOrderMain.OrderComponentID
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough in the post but what i want is : to keep everything except the Amount, where the results will be null 90% of the time, but in those cases i still want to get everything else from the select

Comment: @Cheesus . . . This keeps all invoice items, which is a good guess to what you mean.

Comment: I checked with you query but it does the opposite of what I want, your query display everything that as a Invoice Items.Amount even if it's null, while I want to do is display everything even if the invoiceItems.Amount is null